# Желтый текст выходного дня

Tags: php

```
if ($r["afisha_prem"] == 1) { $prem = '<span style="font-style:italic">Премьера!</span><br />'; }
else { $prem = ''; }
(???) <!--if (date("l",$r["afisha_date"])=="Saturday") {$date = 'color="#ff0064'}-->(???)
```

Если в бд у нас афиша = 1, то выводим премьера, иначе пусто. А как сделать, если "выходной день", то цвет текста желтый?

Answer (score 1):

```
<span style="<?php echo 'color: yellow;';?>font-style:italic">Премьера!</span>
```

Можно подставить переменную при необходимости.

```
<span style="<?php echo $date;?>font-style:italic">Премьера!</span>
```

С условием:

```
if ($r["afisha_prem"] == 1) { 
    $prem = '<span style="font-style:italic">Премьера!</span><br />'; 
    } elseif (($r["afisha_date"] == "Saturday") == (date("l") == "Saturday")) { 
        $prem = '<span style="font-style:italic; color: yellow;">Премьера!</span><br />'; 
        echo $prem; 
    }
```

Comment: а как сделать если "выходной день" то цвет текста желтый????

Comment: напишите если не сложно))

Comment: У @Palmervan наверное идея фикс. Как вижу решений уже много, так что пробуйте и у вас получится.

Comment: @Palmervan используйте функцию date(); вместо time(); поскльку time Возвращает количество секунд, прошедших с начала Эпохи Unix (The Unix Epoch, 1 января 1970, 00:00:00 GMT) до текущего времени.

Comment: @archi_sova в вопросе чётко написано что - если в бд 1 то выводим афишу, а если еще и на выходной, то закрасить ее! У вас же переменная `$r["afisha_date"]` принимает значение дня недели а не результат хранимый в БД! По сути же должно быить `и, или` одновеменно!

Comment: Все у меня правильно написано, вы сейчас научите :) у меня сравниваются два результата, а не принимаются значения.

Comment: @archi_sova присваимать time() это уже привычка просто! Можно конечно и обойтись!)

Comment: не будим холиварить, выбрать есть из чего и перелопатить под себя! рассматриваются всетаки методы а не решения)

Comment: @Palmervan Согласен! ;)

Answer (score 0):

[date](http://www.php.ru/manual/function.date.html)

Answer (score 0):

Код в вашем стиле...

```
if(date("N", time()) == '6' or date("N", time()) == '7')
{
    $paint = ' color: #ff0000';
}
else
{
    $paint = '';
}

if($r["afisha_prem"] == 1)
{
    $prem = '<span style="font-style:italic; '.$paint.'">Премьера!</span><br />';
}
else {
    $prem = '';
}

echo $prem;
```

Comment: странно желтым не пишет((

Comment: @step поставьте вместо 6 или 7 - 2, и будет писать!

Comment: нет( как писалось белым так и пишется, даже сегодняшняя дата не  пишется желтым.

Comment: @step скрин прислать?)))

Comment: Все )))) сори люди, бд не я делал, я  просто код правил))) там не было даты вообще, они ручками её вбивали, поэтому и не видел наш код ни даты ни чего))))) все работает, поставил в бд пункт дату, все работает нормально. спасибо!

Comment: if ($r["afisha_holy"] == 1)
   {
    $stye_yellow = 'color:yellow';
   }
   else
   {
    $stye_yellow = '';
   }

сам код собственно, потом в стиле при выводе данных ставим просто стиль и все)))